# For each h3 link, copy to bottom of list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the html code:

```
<li>
  <h3 class="title">
    <a href="http://somewebsite.com/pilots/stanley-robert-austin">Stanley Robert   Austin</a>
  </h3>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
          <p class="search-snippet">...         19/03/1897            First Name:&nbsp;      Stanley <strong>Robert</strong>          Date of Death:&nbsp;      Unknown          Surname:&nbsp;      Austin   ...    Place of Birth:&nbsp;      Foxton, Manawatu            Stanley <strong>Robert</strong> Austin          Royal Aero Club Cert. No.:&nbsp;      5359                   ...</p>
              <p class="search-info">The_107s - <a href="/users/admin" title="View user profile." class="username">admin</a> - 15/10/2014 - 11:14</p>
      </div>
</li>
<li>
  <h3 class="title">
    <a href="http://somewebsite.com/pilots/philip-robert-going">Philip Robert Going</a>
  </h3>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
          <p class="search-snippet">...  of Birth:&nbsp;      Unknown          First Name:&nbsp;      Philip <strong>Robert</strong>          Date of Death:&nbsp;      Unknown          Surname:&nbsp;      Going          Place of Birth:&nbsp;      Unknown            Philip <strong>Robert</strong> Going          Royal Aero Club Cert. No.:&nbsp;      3865                    ...</p>
              <p class="search-info">The_107s - <a href="/users/admin" title="View user profile." class="username">admin</a> - 15/10/2014 - 11:14</p>
      </div>
</li>
```

What I am trying to do is get the title link which is different for every list item, and repeat it as a button at the bottom of  every list element. Here is what I came up with so far:

```
// Add button to search results. Copy from title
  // Search page code.
  if ($('body').hasClass('page-search-node')) {
    $('ol.search-results li h3 a')
    .each(function() {
      var n = jQuery(this).find("ol.search-results li h3 a").html();
      $(n).clone().insertAfter('.search-snippet-info');
    });
  }
```

Can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  var n = jQuery(this).find("ol.search-results li h3 a").html();
  $(n).clone().insertAfter('.search-snippet-info');
```

Should be:

```
  var n = jQuery(this).html();
  $(n).insertAfter('.search-snippet-info');
```

You do not need to traverse the DOM again, it is already traversed. And, `.html()` (you could also use `.text()`) is a string and does not need to be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

You select the wrong elements,your code should be like:

```
    if ($('body').hasClass('page-search-node')) {
    $('ol.search-results li')
    .each(function() {
      var n = jQuery(this).find("h3").find("a").html();
      $(n).clone().insertAfter(jQuery(this).find('.search-snippet-info'));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by changing my code to:

```
// Add button to search results. Copy from title
  // Search page code.
  if ($('body').hasClass('page-search-node')) {
    $('ol.search-results li h3')
    .each(function() {
      var link = $(this).html();
      $(this).parent().find('.search-snippet-info').append(link);
    });
  }
```